# What am I doing wrong and how do I fix it?

Tags: python, sqlite

I am trying to insert data into a sqlite3 table. I have been experimenting with multiple solutions I have found online yet I can't seem to find a solution that works.
My error is

```
    File "C:/Users/jaicedecelis/PycharmProjects/Terminal CRM/main.py", line 29, in <module>
    new_customer_entry()
  File "C:/Users/jaicedecelis/PycharmProjects/Terminal CRM/main.py", line 20, in new_customer_entry
    (firstname, lastname, stocknumber, emailaddress, phonenum1, phonenum2, phonenum3, leaseorbuy))
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

This is my code

```
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect("customerList.db")
c = conn.cursor()


def new_customer_entry():
    firstname = input("First Name: ")
    lastname = input("Last Name: ")
    stocknumber = input("Stock Number: ")
    emailaddress = input("Email Address: ")
    phonenum1 = input("Cell Number: ")
    phonenum2 = input("House Number: ")
    phonenum3 = input("Work Number: ")
    leaseorbuy = input("Lease or Buy?: ")
    c.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS customerProfiles(firstname, lastname, stocknumber, emailaddress, cellphone, housephone, workphone, leaseorbuy)')
    c.execute("INSERT INTO customerProfiles (firstname, lastname, stocknumber, emailaddress, cellphone, housephone, workphone, leaseorbuy) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"
              (firstname, lastname, stocknumber, emailaddress, phonenum1, phonenum2, phonenum3, leaseorbuy))
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()
    print("Customer Profile Added for " + firstname + " " + lastname)

print("Welcome to Atlantic Terminal CRM")

selection = input("N : New, S : Search\n")
if selection == "N" or selection == "n":
    new_customer_entry()
# elif selection == "S" or selection == "s":
    # criteria = input("F : First Name, L: Last Name, S: Stock Number, P: Phone Number\n")
    # if criteria == "f" or criteria == "F":
       # fName = input("First Name: ")
    # if criteria == "l" or criteria == "L":
        # lName = input("Last Name: ")
    # if criteria == "s" or criteria == "S":
        # sNum = input("Stock Number: ")
    # if criteria == "p" or criteria == "P":
        # pNum = input("Phone Number: ")
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a comma on the end of line 20.

```
c.execute("INSERT INTO customerProfiles (firstname, lastname, stocknumber, emailaddress, cellphone, housephone, workphone, leaseorbuy) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)",
              (firstname, lastname, stocknumber, emailaddress, phonenum1, phonenum2, phonenum3, leaseorbuy))
```

(Because you were continuing the rest of  the c.execute() block on the next line.)

Comment: Oh my lord, this had me so confused for an entire hour. Thank you